# My program run slow at first run after compilation, then fast. If I compile it again, it run again slow for first run, and fast for other runs

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, compilation, stack

This program creates a stack with only two char, a and b. I am just doing some exercise. But something weird happends.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct mychar {
    char value;
    struct mychar *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct mychar Mychar;


void push(Mychar ** , char );
void pop(Mychar ** , char );
void printlist(Mychar * );


int main(){
    Mychar *topPtr = NULL;
    push (&topPtr, 'a');
    push (&topPtr, 'b');
    printlist(topPtr);
}


void push(Mychar **tPtr , char newvalue){
    Mychar *newtopPtr = calloc(1,sizeof(Mychar));
    newtopPtr->value = newvalue;
    newtopPtr->nextPtr = *tPtr;
    *tPtr = newtopPtr;
}


void pop(Mychar ** , char );


void printlist(Mychar *cPtr){
    while (cPtr!=NULL){
        printf("%c\n", cPtr->value);
        cPtr = cPtr->nextPtr;
    }
}
```

If I compile and run it, it takes some seconds to display the output:

```
$ ./"stack_dyn" 
b
a
```

But in the next runs, it's fast. Also, if I compile it again, it's slow at first run, and fast from second run. Why?

Comment: What system are you running it on? OS and version?

Comment: The program is simple and should not cause the behavior you describe. Could it be disk caching?

Comment: @EricPostpischil MacOS 10.15.4. btw now it doesn't do that anymore... but I am still curious why did it happened?

Comment: This may be [notarization checking](https://sigpipe.macromates.com/2020/macos-catalina-slow-by-design/).